# How to setup TeamCity under IIS?

Tags: version-control, teamcity

Any ideas?

Comment: Why? Team City includes its own web server and can be installed as a Windows service.

Comment: because you want to run iis and teamcity on the same box, and have them both on :80?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [Tomcat and the IIS connector for Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html).

Comment: Can you give any more detail?

Comment: Team city runs under Tomcat since it's a Java web app.  In order to hook it up under IIS, you need the IIS connector to hook tomcat up with IIS.

Comment: Information on this is here: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Comment: @Ken: I allowed myself to edit your useful link into the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

With IIS 7.5 you can use Application Request Routing to route requests at `teamcity.server.domain.com:80` to Tomcat at `server.domain.com:81`. I would consider this approach superior since the Tomcat Connector seems a bit flaky under WS2008 x64.

Jon Alb has a good writeup on how to configure TeamCity plus IIS on WS2008:

- [Part1](http://jonalb.com/post/2010/10/23/TeamCity-On-Port-80-In-IIS.aspx)
- [Part2](http://www.jonalb.com/post/2010/10/30/TeamCity-via-IIS-on-port-80-using-a-reverse-proxy-Part-2-host-filtering.aspx)

Additionally, you need to ensure that your DNS can resolve `teamcity.server.domain.com` to `server.domain.com`. My IIS server needed a `ipconfig /registerdns` to update its DNS entry correctly. Correctly means in this case to create a *Domain* entry in the domain.com lookup zone for `server`, a simple A-Record does not suffice. In that domain, you need to create a CNAME record for * , so any subdomain will be redirected to `server.domain.com`

A big problem I ran into is that IIS 7.5 seems to no longer correctly write the `applicationHost.config` file, so the port number won't endup being persisted. This will result in a nasty `400.0 Bad Request` error because the MAX_FORWARDS limit will be reached (the request is rooted in circles).

To fix this, add the following to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`:

```
<webFarms>
  <webFarm name="teamcity" enabled="true" adminUserName="" adminPassword="[enc:AesProvider:2blZ7roifGTktpn8zBBuVQ==:enc]" primaryServer="">
    <server address="localhost" enabled="true">
      <applicationRequestRouting httpPort="YOURPORTHERE!!!" />
    </server>
    <applicationRequestRouting>
      <loadBalancing algorithm="WeightedRoundRobin" />
      <protocol reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="true" />
    </applicationRequestRouting>
  </webFarm>
</webFarms>
```

**Edit** If you are running other sites, and getting a 404, besides following Part 2 you need to create a dummy site to catch the hostname as the below Ian Patrick Hughes answer states.

Comment: Almost half a year later I want to come back and at least share the fact that I am running teamcity on an ubuntu server with lighttpd as a proxy now. The windows setup had some issues with connecting a Mac OS buikd agent that I couldn't figure out. Setting up Teamcity on Ubuntu was painless and easy.

Answer (score 10):

To add to Johannes Rudolph's answer...The Jon Alb article is the best for a simple breakdown on exposing Team City in IIS 7.5. The only thing to mention is that if you are running other sites on that server instance, after you follow through his [second part](http://www.jonalb.com/post/2010/10/30/TeamCity-via-IIS-on-port-80-using-a-reverse-proxy-Part-2-host-filtering.aspx), you might need to create a dummy site looking for a subdomain host header value because it seemed like IIS never executed my farm re-write url if there was no site that matched. However, this should also allow you employ HTTP Authentication if you want to protect your Team City login page on port 80.

Comment: This is a pretty nutty step, but my experience was the same. When I installed ASP.Net 3.5 & 4.5 my farm redirects stopped working and I had to both manually edit the config with Johannes Rudolph's instructions and add dummy sites matching my teamcity and teamcity.domain HTTP_HOST rewrite conditions. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yeah, it was a few years ago that I encountered this issue. I'm honestly surprised that people are still resolving it in a similar fashion!

Answer (score 5):

A Step by Step Guide to Hosting TeamCity in IIS 7

http://blog.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-teamcity-in-iis-7/

Comment: That is a great step by step tutorial.. but at the end it doesn't work on mine :(